# Черный экран после изменения разрешения в линукс сентос 7

Tags: linux, centos7

У меня linux centos 7 на пк ,подключен 4к монитор через display port, и после того , как я изменил разрешение в системе, после входа и ввода пароля, становиться черный экран, только терминал могу запустить.

Comment: отпишись в итоге под ответом - получилось что или нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну терминал это уже немало.

#### system-config-display

Если вопрос только в разрешении то все просто - проставьте то, что нужно

```sh
system-config-display --reconfig --set-resolution=1920x1080
```

сам конфиг можно посмотреть по пути

```
/etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

если вдруг команда не найдена - можно установить пакет следующей командой:

```sh
sudo yum install system-config-display
```

если вдруг возникнут какие-то проблемы, то в конце ответа есть второй способ

#### важное замечание

Чтобы не напортачить и не указать неподдерживаемый режим - лучше сначала узнать что можно указывать, а что нельзя.

поддерживаемые режимы и устройства можно посмотреть с помощью

```sh
sudo xrandr
```

мне на рабочей машине выдал следующее

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected primary (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 287mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00    60.05    60.00    50.04  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1440x576      50.00  
   1440x480      59.94  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94    59.93
```

#### способ №2

с помощью xrandr, кстати тоже можно установить разрешение:

```
xrandr --fb 1920x1080
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь, уже не могу сказать, помогло бы, да я поставил изначально неподдержиыаемое разрешение и поэтому все вылетело у меня, к сожвлению пришлось удалить все и снова поставить виндовс и линукс потом, но толка не получилось , потому что похоже вивадо только лицензию можно поставить на линукс и у меня не было больше времени и так потратил на это 2 дня , все перепробовав , все равно еще раз благодарю за саппорт.

Comment: @RussellOcean, обращайтесь)